# Under what conditions are there only a finite number of distinct subsets $S$ of $W$ such that $S$ generates $W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$. Under what conditions are there only a finite number of distinct subsets $S$ of $W$ such that $S$ generates $W$? If $W$ is finite then obviously  there only a finite number of distinct subsets $S$ of $W$ such that $S$ generates $W$? Now let $W$ be infinite ; if $W$ is finite dimensional , then for every $x \in W$ , $W $ \ $\{x\}$ being infinite , spans $W$ now as $W$ is infinite , there are infinitely many distinct $W $ \ $\{x\}$ which spans $W$ , so if $W$ is infinite then $W$ cannot be finite dimensional . But I cannot figure out what if $W$ is infinite dimensional ? Moreover I think that $W$ is a subspace is redundant , we can just work with $W$ as a vector space

Comment: If the vector space is over an infinite field there are never finitely many bases unless the subspace is trivial.

Comment: What do you mean by infinite? $\mathbb R$ is an infinite set (it contains infinitely many elements), but it is a finite dimensional real vector space...

Comment: @MattSamuel: But a finite set S can only have finitely many subsets , so whatever the base field be finite or infinite , there are only finitely many generating sets ! Am I wrong ?

Comment: Suppose the subspace is 1-dimensional generated by $v$. For any nonzero real number $a$, $\{av\}$ is a basis of this subspace. I have constructed infinitely many generating sets.

Comment: @MattSamuel: But $a v$ must be a vector , so must be in $W$ , so $W$ is not finite , so a finite set cannot be  a vector space over an infinite field .... please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: If a vector space over an infinite field is finite, then it is trivial, correct.

Comment: @MattSamuel : So umm , what is the conclusion :) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only vector spaces that have only a finite number of spanning sets are the finite vector spaces: the $0$-dimensional vector space over any field, and the finite dimensional vector spaces over *finite* fields.

Comment: why ? please elaborate why infinite vector spaces cannot have only finitely many generating sets?

Comment: what is the span of $W$ \ $\{x\}$ ?

Comment: In an infinite vector space, every vector $x$ admits a vector $y$ such that $x\notin\{y,x-y\}$, while $x=y+(x-y)$. This shows that $x\in\operatorname{span}(V\setminus\{x\})$ in such cases; the span therefore is all of $V$. With infinitely many choices of $x$, this gives infinitely many different sets that span $V$.

Comment: I think your comment is a very good explanation and should be added to the answer